# function that returns invalid if input is in wrong format

Tags: python-3.x

I've written a function that reads a data frame and converts day week (1-7) to (Monday to Sunday), Month (1-12) to Season (Summer to Spring) and time (00:00:00 - 23:59:00) to (Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night) 
NOTE: I've already completed this part and i just need to add code which will perform the action below

There are lines in various columns which contain 'UNKNOWN'. if my function attempts to convert a row where any of the inputs (day, month, time) are in the incorrect format (i.e. they contain UNKNOWN) then it needs to return 'INVALID' in all outputs. What can I add to my existing code to do this? I also need to be able to filter out these invalid entries later. Any help/genera advice is appreciated! thanks!

```
#function to convert month, day and time
import datetime
def compute_day_year(n):
    Season = data.loc[n,'Crash_Month']
    if 1 >= data.loc[n,'Crash_Month'] <= 2 or data.loc[n,'Crash_Month']== 12:
        print('Summer')

    elif 3 >= data.loc[n,'Crash_Month'] <=5:
        print('Autumn')

    elif 6 >= data.loc[n,'Crash_Month'] <=8:
        print('Winter')

    elif 9 >= data.loc[n,'Crash_Month'] <=11:
        print('Spring') 


    DayWeek = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day']
    if data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 1:
        print('Monday')

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 2:
        print('Tuesday') 

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 3:
        print('Wednesday')   

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 4:
        print('Thursday')      

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 5:
        print('Friday')

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 6:
        print('Saturday')

    elif data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'] == 7:
        print('Sunday')

    TPDay = timeobj
    if timeobj >= datetime.time(6,0,0) <=datetime.time(11,59,0):
            print('Morning')

    elif timeobj >= datetime.time(12,0,0) <=datetime.time(17,59,0):
            print('Afternoon')

    elif timeobj >= datetime.time(18,0,0) <=datetime.time(23,59,0):
            print('Evening')

    elif timeobj >= datetime.time(0,0,0) <=datetime.time(5,59,0):
            print('Night')

 #compute day year is the day/row to convert
compute_day_year(0)
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing everything directly you could add the strings to a variable. This will allow you to just set it to Invalid if something is wrong.
So every `print(text)` should be replaced with `output += text`.
Don't forget to add

```
return output
```

at the end of your function.

---

Some improvements

Rewrite your elif statements by using a **dictionary** or even simpler a **list**:

```
# this is a list which stores the days
days = ['Monday', etc.]

DayWeek = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day']
# this line checks you're giving a good argument (day 1-7)
if 0 < DayWeek <= 7:
    # this gets the day at the given index
    # -1 because lists start with the index 0, not 1
    output += days[DayWeek - 1]
else:
    # wrong arguments given
    return "Invalid"
```

---

this variable is unnecessary

```
TPDay = timeobj
```

either delete it or use it

---

```
elif timeobj >= datetime.time(0,0,0) <= datetime.time(5,59,0):
```

will check `if timeobj >= datetime.time(0,0,0)` and
if `datetime.time(0,0,0) <= datetime.time(5,59,0)`

I guess you want to check if timeobj is between the 0:00 and 6:00, so you should write

```
elif datetime.time(0,0,0) <= timeobj < datetime.time(6,0,0):
# < 6 is the same as <= 5
```

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback/help- I have less than a month of experience with coding in general (as you can surely tell) so I'm trying to learn as quickly as possible.

Comment: Also! could you explain what's going on with the code block where you've suggested to rewrite my elif statements? How/Why does this work?